# What is the Pay with Square app's custom url scheme?

Tags: url

I am looking for the custom URL scheme for the Pay with Square app that customers use to pay with their smartphone - not the Square card reader for merchants.  I know this custom url - square://.  I found one posted here for the Pay with Square - square-pay://, but it does not work.  I want to launch the app separately via an app I am building.

Comment: anyone knows about Skrill?

Answer (score 1):

`square-pay://` is working for me. I just added it to Launch Center, and it popped right up.

Answer (score 0):

The Custom URL Scheme square-register:// will simply launch the Square Register app.

The scheme that supports other details getting passed is square-commerce-v1://
But you have to get approved as a developer to use the scheme.

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/index.html#initiating-a-payment